# Proper placement of image using css

Tags: html, css

I have an image. This image should have 100% height. So, in my CSS, I defined height: 100%. The problem is the respective width, since this image is a panorama, it will certainly exceed the viewport dimensions. I don't want this to happen. Is there a way like overflow: hidden to completely hide the portion of the image after the maximum viewport width.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="http://photoblogstop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Sierra_HDR_Panorama_DFX8048_2280x819_Q40_wm_mini.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#image {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle as well.
http://jsfiddle.net/AH3Hd/

Comment: Doesn't `overflow:hidden` actually work in the `#image`  because if i try it in the fiddle it works more or less

Comment: i din't try it on img tag. i tried the same on a div container for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to your div. You need to give it a width or it will just auto adjust to whatever its contents are.

```
div {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AH3Hd/4/

Answer (score 0):

To use `overflow:hidden;`, you need to specify a width to the `div`, otherwise the browser will not know when to hide. I edited your fiddle to show that:

```
#image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AH3Hd/6/

Comment: Does this alter the aspect ratio?

Comment: yes, this worked on the image, but the overflow is only hidden, isn't it? this caused the horizontal scrollbar on the browser to appear.

Comment: @microman The overflow should be completely hidden, with no scrollbars. and no, this does not alter the aspect ratio in any form, it simply crops away the extra space. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#image {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:300px; // Depends on the size you want
    width:300px;
}
#image img{
    height:100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwvanveelen/AH3Hd/7/